# Why does contrastive loss and triplet loss have the margin element in them?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, triplet-loss

Trying to learn Siamese networks for ranking tasks from [here](https://youtu.be/6e65XfwmIWE?t=1015), I find it hard to understand why triplet loss and contrastive losses have the "margin" element in them.

The contrastive loss

$L(A, B) = y|f(A) - f(B)| + (1-y)max(0, m-|f(A) - F(B)|)$

The triplet loss

$L(A, P, N) = max(0, |f(A) - f(P)| - |f(A) - f(N)| + m) $

both have the margin `m`, which doesn't allow samples to be pushed passed it.

[In the lecture](https://youtu.be/6e65XfwmIWE?t=1015), Prof. Laura Leal-Taixé says:

> I want to keep separating them (the samples), until we hit a margin
> `m`. And the idea is that it makes no sense to actually push $f(A)$
> and $f(B)$ further apart if they are already as far as the margin `m`.
> ... I am not going to spend any energy in pulling them even further
> away.

---

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/573582/why-does-contrastive-loss-distinguish-positive-from-negative-samples/573585?noredirect=1#comment1059253_573585) it is explained why we want to bound the loss.

Still, I would like to understand how does changing the value of `m` change the output, from the user's perspective, meaning, how does it affect clustering, or classification accuracy or other metrics? Why choose large or small `m` when engineering a system?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience when experimenting with audio file classification task, the choice of `m` really depends on your task, and your model. When I chose `m = 0.2`, the network almost made no effort to minimize the triplet loss to zero after few epochs. One of the other reasons was because the 3 samples I chose were not informative enough.

So how to find the proper value of `m`? I had to check to scores of the trained model given the margin is `0.2`, I realized that the scores on the dataset (of samples) were absurdly large (for example, some sample was scored 5 while the other was core 30!). This time, I had to adjust `m` empirically to a sufficiently large number (say, 9), in order to better separate the two classes. So to answer your question, yes, it does affect the capability of the network to separate the positive and negative classes.